# why can't I select all rows added with 30 minutes in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, innodb

I have a dateAdded field that is a DATETIME type.  I'm trying the query

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE dateAdded > now() - interval 30 minute
```

It returns 0 rows even though there are a lot of rows created within 30 minutes.  When I switch the greater than sign to a less than sign every row in the table is returned.  I am using MySQL 5.6.28 and an InnoDB table.  What reason could cause this not to work? I am doing a similar query on other tables with a DATETIME type and it works fine.

Comment: It should work. Are you sure it is DATETIME? Are you querying the correct DB?

Comment: Also, any chance that `dateAdded` has different timezone than the server's or session's `now()`?

Comment: how do I check the value of now() to confirm if this is the problem?

Comment: Simply `SELECT NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE`

Comment: Also, it's definitely DATETIME and I'm doing the query directly in Sequel Pro.
     `dateAdded` datetime DEFAULT NULL,

Comment: @Cascader This seems like the reason thank you.  30 minutes from NOW() is returning 2017-10-24 14:44:25 but in the database the most recent dateAdded time is 2017-10-24 11:14:21

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a difference between the timezone used on the column (i.e. application inserting `dateAdded` data) and the timezone used on the client side issuing the query.

`SELECT NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE` proved that difference.

Comment: Then you should probably be using `TIMESTAMP` instead of `DATETIME`.  Neither stores a timezone.  Instead, `DATETIME` stores whatever you say -- no TZ adjustment; `TIMEZONE` adjusts between client's TZ and UTC -- both storing and retrieving.